# module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app'

Tags: python, firebase, streamlit, pyrebase

I currently use streamlit and wanted to integrate to firebase. I have been encountered the problem "no module named 'pyrebased'" and finally can install it.

however I face another problem said that "**module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app'"**

this what I encounter in the streamlit local host

[image]

and here is my code

```
# ------ Modules
import pyrebase
import streamlit as st
from datetime import datetime

#------ Configuration Key
firebaseConfig = {
  'apiKey': "AIzaSyBvTe3A9M0R0HDaumOHhw_knSTEYqSmnio",
  'authDomain': "gnseastreamlit1.firebaseapp.com",
  'projectId': "gnseastreamlit1",
  'databaseURL' : "https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/gnseastreamlit1/database/gnseastreamlit1-default-rtdb/data/~2F",
  'storageBucket': "gnseastreamlit1.appspot.com",
  'messagingSenderId': "263267683418",
  'appId' : "1:263267683418:web:549f4369140beb80e95c63",
  'measurementId': "G-33QXY92WQG"
}

# ------ Firebase Authentication
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()

# ------ Database
db = firebase.database()
storage = firebase.storage()
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your **project file** in the same folder which has **pyrebase** package installed

Source: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you installed the right version of Pyrebase? I had some errors when I ran `pip install pyrebase`. However, I found out that I actually needed to run `pip install pyrebase4` for it to work as shown in this post about [pyrebase and fastAPI](https://pythonalgos.com/python-firebase-authentication-integration-with-fastapi/) for authentication.